# Windows PowerShell doesn’t use my SSH keys

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, public-key

I have a Git repository hosted on Bitbucket. I can connect to this using Git Bash terminal, which uses my public key defined in my **H:** drive (network drive), but if I try the same from Windows PowerShell, it just runs through all the authentication methods before ending on asking for a password (last resort).

Why doesn’t Windows PowerShell read my public key?

Comment: Which `ssh.exe` are you invoking when you call it in Powershell? The default installation option for Git Bash only put `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd` into your `PATH`, so  other command line utilities in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` are not available in posh. Maybe in your Powershell prompt, when you call `ssh`, you are invoking another file.